# Read barcode which has control characters/invisible characters in it.(using c# and wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Requirement:-
To create a Windows application to read barcode which has control characters/invisible characters in it.(using c# and wpf)

I have attached a sample solution  which I tried but I have the following issue:-

The solution works fine for barcode without control characters and also for barcodes having ESC or Enter as control characters.
But for control characters like [TAB] , [SHIFT] , [DEL] ,[BACKSPACE] it doesn’t works correctly.

For example:-

If I manually put : 1234[ALT]009[RELEASE ALT]5678[ENTER]: simulates the invisible character
But  if I try reading the same via bar code(see attachment for bar code) the entire things gets cleared out. (Check in sample solution)
When I tried to figure out the reason on my end,  I found ‘PreviewTextInput’ event is not raised for the invisible character(tab control).

Please can anyone suggest an alternative solution or what changes to be made in the solution I shared so 
that I achieve the functionality required.

[Sample Solution and Barcode uploaded](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhZZ9_N_H7j4g1TKxSj4Yu5sGnSU)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify what kind of barcode? There are plenty of standards. Not all of them can encode just any character set.

Answer (score 0):

Your TextBox does not accept Tabs use

```
AcceptsTab="True"
```

to make it accept this instead jump to next tabstop. In WPF it is better to use Binding instead CodeBehind, so I created a ViewModel for you handling the Input.

So as first step I created a ViewModel for you:

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _inputText;
    private ObservableCollection<String> _resultList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private String _resultText;

    public string InputText
    {
        get => _inputText;
        set
        {
            if (value == _inputText) return;
            _inputText = value;
            ProcessInput();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void ProcessInput()
    {
        ResultList.Clear();
        ResultText = GetUiFriendlyBarCode(InputText);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ResultList
    {
        get => _resultList;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _resultList)) return;
            _resultList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string ResultText
    {
        get => _resultText;
        set
        {
            if (value == _resultText) return;
            _resultText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private string GetUiFriendlyBarCode(String input)
    {
        StringBuilder barCodeToDisplay = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char character in input.ToString())
        {
            var uiFriendlyCharCode = GetUiFriendlyCharCode((int)character);
            barCodeToDisplay.Append(uiFriendlyCharCode);
            ResultList.Add(uiFriendlyCharCode);
        }
        return barCodeToDisplay.ToString();
    }

//... implement GetUiFriendlyCharCode and INotifyPropertyChnaged
```

Add the Bindings in Xaml

```
    <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=Scan}">_Scan</Label>
    <TextBox AcceptsTab="True" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Scan" Height="50" Text="{Binding InputText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <!-- List all characters separately -->
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="Log" ItemsSource="{Binding ResultList}"/>
    <!-- 
        Show a string to the user that clearly shows any invisible characters.
    -->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3">Result</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Result" Text="{Binding ResultText}"/>
```

And than add the DataSource in MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```